# Data extraction from Matlab structs

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab struct from which I would like to extract data.

I have written a few lines of code which does the job, but I am interested in a less cumbersome procedure using curly braces. How can I do this?

[image]

My code is copied below:

```
area = table2array(cell2table({result2.Area}))';
area = area';
centroid_coordinates = table2array(cell2table({result2.Centroid}));
centroid_coordinates = reshape(centroid_coordinates, 2, length(result2))';
bounding_box = (table2array(cell2table({result2.BoundingBox})))';
bounding_box = reshape(bounding_box, 4, length(result2))';
```

Comment: You might find [this forum post](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/299135-is-it-possible-to-extract-all-fields-from-a-structure-automatically) to be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to concatenate the output of struct indexing:

```matlab
centroid_coordinates = table2array(cell2table({result2.Centroid}));
centroid_coordinates = reshape(centroid_coordinates, 2, length(result2))';
```

With that said perhaps [this post on MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/439663-horizontally-concatinating-the-fields-of-a-structure-with-different-dimensions) is relevant.

In this case, seeing that these are same-dimension items in the structs you are dealing with, you should be able to use `[res.Centroid]` in brackets to horizontally concatenate data, or `vertcat(res.Centroid)` to vertically concatenate data.

I'm using the following repro data which is a struct array with similarly shaped data to your image:

```matlab
cent1 = [1,2];
cent2 = [3,4];
res(1).Centroid = cent1;
res(2).Centroid = cent2;
```

And reproduce your output with:

```matlab
% Using method in question
withCurly = table2array(cell2table({res.Centroid}));
withCurly = reshape(withCurly, 2, length(res))';

% Using vertcat
withVert = vertcat(res.Centroid);

isequal(withCurly, withVert)
% ans = 1
```

References:

- [vertcat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html)
- [horzcat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html)